# behaviour of MySQL 'IN' operator when fed with JSON values

Tags: mysql, json, in-operator

This statement

```
select 'foo' in ('foo', 'bar');
```

returns 1 as expected.

This

```
select json_extract('["foo"]', '$[0]') = 'foo';
```

also returns 1 as expected.

However, this

```
 select json_extract('["foo"]', '$[0]') in ('foo', 'bar');
```

unuexpectedly returns 0. Even more strangely, if written with additional quotes

```
select json_extract('["foo"]', '$[0]') in ('"foo"', '"bar"');
```

it returns 1 instead. But this does not work with simple equality, as

```
select json_extract('["foo"]', '$[0]') = '"foo"';
```

returns 0.

So the question is: why "IN" and "=" behave differently *only* when fed with JSON results?

Comment: `select json_extract('["foo"]', '$[0]') in ('foo', 'bar');` returns 1 on my system.... (MySQL8.0.25/Windows)

Answer (score 3):

Version-dependent. MySQL 5.7 needs in additional JSON_UNQUOTE().

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bcfea5bebdc270c77e1edbc2c384909f

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bcfea5bebdc270c77e1edbc2c384909f